# Data from check box not going to database in IE and Firefox

Tags: php, javascript

This is my code to enter values into the database:

```
if (isset($_POST['submit']))
{
$check1=$_POST['chk1'];
$con = mysql_connect("144.100.166.07","arj","1lgh");
if (!$con)
  {
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
  }
mysql_select_db("arjunJalaaDe", $con);

for($i=0;$i<sizeof($check1);$i++)
{
$sql="INSERT INTO testing (word) values ('". $check1[$i]."')";
mysql_query($sql) or die('Error: ' . mysql_error());
}
mysql_close($con);
echo("its done");
}
```

The values are taken from checkboxes.

```
<input type="checkbox" name="chk1[]" id="chk" value="pic1" onclick="chkcontrol(0)"></input>
```

It works fine on Chrome but does not insert in IE and Firefox.

Comment: is there a proper form in there somewhere?

Comment: you should debug function.. .in chkcontrol function. .try to alert the checkbox value. .then you will get..

Answer (score 1):

Well, there are differances in how browsers handle incorrect javascript.
I had similar problem some time ago when one browser did all the things correctly when I used jquery, but others didn't.
So error is in javascript. And the only javascript call I see is onlcick event.
Maybe try, `onclick="javascript:chkcontrol(0)"`

Comment: its checking the boxes with the onclick event. but not inserting the values with the script above

Answer (score 0):

Your problem will be in your Javascript.  Browsers have no effect over server side code like php.  Take a look at the debugger in ie or firefox to find out what javascript error you are getting.

Comment: the client side script is jus checking the number of checkboxes checked. the values are getting inserted on server side

Comment: I understand that, but what I'm saying is that the browser you use has no effect on how PHP works.